# Is there a way to pass an object through sessions and use its functions?

Tags: php, session, object, parameter-passing

My understanding is that when you serialize an object and pass it through a session, for example, from index.php page to securePage.php, SESSION just passes that objects data, therefore, you can not use that object's functions. The only way is to create a new object on securePage.php with the data you have passed.... Is there a way to pass an actual object and then use it's functions without creating a brand new object on securePage.php.

Example:

```
$randomObj = new rndObject;
$_SESSION['object'] = serialize($randomObj);
```

and securePage.php

```
$whatever = unserialize($_SESSION['object']);

//below code won't work and say something like
//Fatal error: Call to a member function checkAccess() on a non-object in 
//securePage.php on line 39
echo $whatever->checkAccess();
```

Comment: You can simply assign the object to the session variable `$_SESSION['object'] = $randomObj`, it is not necessary to serialize it yourself. The same works for loading from the session (if the class is known at the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of, to get the object which has been loaded into SESSION, you need to include the class definition somewhere before calling unserialize and it will work as you expect, but it will still, technically, create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use __sleep() and __wakeup() magic methods (that's what it's for) :

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/13/0

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: The object will be serialized/deserialized anyway, you can't pass a living object to another page. Including the class before loading the object from the session, will result in a new instance of the object, and that's what CodeCrack probably wants.

Comment: @martinstoeckli : Did I say the contrary ? Watch the examples from those URLs. Of course, objects are serialized since sessions are anything but text. Anyway, those magic methods can help you formating your serialization and make other actions while doing so. My answer should be a comment to cwallenpoole 's answer, I aknowlegde that.

Comment: Sorry, i understood that __sleep() and __wakeup() would help getting his serialized object back.